# Jquery selector for click on background + element?

Tags: jquery, css, html, click, selector

I cant seem to find a correct way to make a selector,
It's supposed to fire clicks only on the background of a DIV, and on the main image - if there is one,
but if I click on some other elements located in that div - like a hrefs etc - it should do nothing.

I tried this:

```
$('#SHOWCASE, #SHOWCASE > img')
```

Showcase - is the ID of the DIV, and img is the image attached directly to it.
However if I add .Click function to it, it still triggers on whatever element is in that div, like links etc, note that these links also have absolute position.

So is there any solution for this?

Comment: can you put up the markup it would make it easer to answer

Comment: this is because you selected the id of the div to apply the event if you want the event to be fired on specific element you can give a class to all those elements and give them the event as:
$('.class_name').click(function(){blah blah blah.....});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the simplest way, just test whether the clicked element is the element you bound the handler to:

```
$('<selector>').click(function(event) {
    if(event.target === this) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

**Reference**: [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behaviour because events bubble up the DOM. You should check the [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) inside the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to see what element was *originally* clicked on:

```
$('#SHOWCASE').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('#SHOWCASE, #SHOWCASE > img').is(e.target)) {
        // Only do something if it was those elements.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop other elements in that div from bubbling up. Something like jQuery's stopPropagation() should do the trick. Add that to all the children of #SHOWCASE.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hello, #hello > img').on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target == this) {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```